# Spring JMS with JBoss 7.11 (HornetQ)

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, netty, hornetq, spring-jms

I am trying to create a sample JMS application. All I want it to do is start up, and have the producer send a message to the consumer when data is sent to an endpoint.

I am having trouble with my spring configuration, and I don't know what dependencies I need to bring in (and what versions) with Maven.  I started with a simple Roo project.

Firstly, does my spring xml look ok, and secondly, are my maven dependencies right? From the error I get, I think I've got an outdated dependency being pulled in from Maven. I've also added a guest user/role to my jboss configuration.

Here is the relevant section of my spring xml:

```
<bean id="jnditemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">remote://127.0.0.1:4447</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">guest</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">password1</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="connectionfactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jnditemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean id="destination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jnditemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="jms/queue/test"/>
</bean>
<bean id="credentialsconnectionfactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionfactory"/>
    <property name="username" value="guest"/>
    <property name="password" value="password1"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jmstemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="credentialsconnectionfactory"/>
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="destination"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="credentialsconnectionfactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="destination"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="receiver"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sender" class="com.example.web.Producer">
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmstemplate"/>
</bean>
<bean id="receiver" class="com.example.web.Consumer"/>
```

Here is the relevant section of my POM:

```
        <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hornetq.client.version>2.3.0.Final</hornetq.client.version>
 ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-core-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hornetq.client.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-jms-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hornetq.client.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-beta-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-jms</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-logging</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-transports</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And the relevant section of my jboss standalone.xml:

```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
        <hornetq-server>
            <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
            <journal-file-size>10240</journal-file-size>
            <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

            <connectors>
                <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </netty-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </connectors>

            <acceptors>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </netty-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </acceptors>

            <security-settings>
                <security-setting match="#">
                    <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                </security-setting>
            </security-settings>

            <address-settings>
                <address-setting match="#">
                    <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                    <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                    <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                </address-setting>
            </address-settings>

            <jms-connection-factories>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                    </entries>
                </connection-factory>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                    <transaction mode="xa"/>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                    </connectors>
                    <entries>
                        <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                    </entries>
                </pooled-connection-factory>
            </jms-connection-factories>

            <jms-destinations>
                <jms-queue name="testQueue">
                    <entry name="queue/test"/>
                      <entry name="java:/queue/test"/>
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-queue name="DemoQueue">
                    <entry name="/queue/DemoQueue"/>
                </jms-queue>
                <jms-topic name="testTopic">
                    <entry name="topic/test"/>
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/test"/>
                </jms-topic>
            </jms-destinations>
        </hornetq-server>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
</profile>
```

and the error I receive when I try to start it up through eclipse/vmware vFabric

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hornetq.utils.HornetQThreadFactory.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least some dependencies in the pom.xml are flat out wrong. Look at the bottom for `hornetq-logging`, `hornetq-transports`, `hornetq-jms` etc. These do not exist anymore in the 2.3.X releases and should be removed.

As a rule, if you have any JAR from the main HornetQ project, it should use the same version. Remove all those jars using `2.0.0.GA`. Some of those were renamed, in either case, you should try to only have `org.hornetq` JARs using the same version. In the case of your pom that would be `2.3.0-Final`. BTW, the latest version is `2.3.2-Final`, and you should upgrade to that IMHO.

IIRC `hornetq-jms` was broken into `hornetq-jms-server` or `hornetq-jms-client`. You probably want `hornetq-jms-client`. Core was also broken into `hornetq-core-client` and `hornetq-server`.

Search for JARs available with version number `2.3.2.Final` here https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;quick~org.hornetq (do some more advanced search).